# How do you apply multiple client certificate dynamically to OkHttp Client without rebuilding the client

Tags: android, okhttp, client-certificates

I have an Android application that should be able to connect to multiple servers with different client certificates respectively.

What is the proper way to dynamically add multiple client certificates to OkHttp client?

Currently, when I apply a new Certificate I am calling this custom method:

```kotlin
private fun applyCertificate(certificatePath: String, password: String) {
    // load certificate into KeyStore
    FileInputStream(path).use {
      clientKeyStore.load(it, password.toCharArray())
    }
    // load KeyStore into KeyManagerFactory
    val keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509")
    keyManagerFactory.init(clientKeyStore, null)
    // Initialize the SSL Context
    sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.keyManagers, tmf.trustManagers, SecureRandom())
    
    // call newBuilder and set new socketFactory
    okHttpClient = okHttpClient.newBuilder()
      .sslSocketFactory(sslContext.socketFactory, tmf.trustManagers[0] as X509TrustManager)
      .build()
  }
```

My concern is

- When I add multiple certificates dynamically, I will be setting a new `SSLSocketFactory` into the the OkHttpClient multiple times,  is this safe to do?

I am not sure if there are better ways of doing this without rebuilding the OkHttpClient.

I did notice that there's the library `okhttp-tls`, is this a better library for this kind of configuration?

## `Edit:`

Just to clarify,

I am initializing a global instance of okHttpClient when I create our application. This global instance may be used by multiple application components simultaneously for the lifetime of the application.

```kotlin
fun initialSetup() {
  okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()
  ...
}
```

then I get an a secured request that needs Certificate authentication:

```kotlin
val call = okHttpClient.newCall(
  Request.Builder().url("https://pki.service.com/resource1")
    .build()
)
val httpResponse = call.execute()

....

if (httpResponse.code == HTTP_CERTIFICATE_AUTHENTICATION) {
  val certificate = getCertificatePathForServer()

  httpClient.applyCertificate(certificate.path, certificate.password)
  ...
  // retry call
}
```

and `applyCertificate()` looks like I explained above:

```kotlin
private fun applyCertificate(certificatePath: String, password: String) {
    // load certificate into KeyStore
    FileInputStream(path).use {
      clientKeyStore.load(it, password.toCharArray())
    }
    // load KeyStore into KeyManagerFactory
    val keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509")
    keyManagerFactory.init(clientKeyStore, null)
    // Initialize the SSL Context
    sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.keyManagers, tmf.trustManagers, SecureRandom())

    // call newBuilder and set new socketFactory
    okHttpClient = okHttpClient.newBuilder()
      .sslSocketFactory(sslContext.socketFactory, tmf.trustManagers[0] as X509TrustManager)
      .build()
  }
```

My corcern is that as I am rebulding the OkHttpClient everytime I add a new certificate, components that currently use the global OkHttpClient instance might see undesired side effects, for example pending requests not completing or worse, crashing. Is it safe to rebuild an OkHttpClient instance that may currently be in use with `okHttpClient.newBuilder()`?

Answer (score 1):

> I did notice that there's the library okhttp-tls, is this a better library for this kind of configuration?

Yes, that library is well suited to this.

```
HandshakeCertificates clientCertificates = new HandshakeCertificates.Builder()
    .addTrustedCertificate(...))
    .build();
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .sslSocketFactory(clientCertificates.sslSocketFactory(), clientCertificates.trustManager())
    .build();
```

Comment: It seems that even if I use `HandshakeCertificates` I would still need to rebuild the `OkHttpClient` after I add a new Certificate. If this safe? even if I there are some other calls pending with the "older" `OkHttpClient` instance, will it just wrok?

Comment: I've updated the post to add more clarification to my question

Comment: It safe to rebuild an `OkHttpClient` instance that is currently be in use with `okHttpClient.newBuilder()`.